# How to split a spark dataframe column of ArrayType(StructType) to multiple columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading xml using databricks spark xml with below schema. the subelement X_PAT can occur more than one time, to handle
this I have used arraytype(structtype),ne xt transformation is to create multiple columns out of this single column.

```
<root_tag>
   <id>fff9</id>
   <X1000>
      <X_PAT>
         <X_PAT01>IC</X_PAT01>
         <X_PAT02>EDISUPPORT</X_PAT02>
         <X_PAT03>TE</X_PAT03>
      </X_PAT>
      <X_PAT>
         <X_PAT01>IC1</X_PAT01>
         <X_PAT02>EDISUPPORT1</X_PAT02>
         <X_PAT03>TE1</X_PAT03>
      </X_PAT>
   </X1000>
</root_tag>
```

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

jar_path = "/Users/nsrinivas/com.databricks_spark-xml_2.10-0.4.1.jar"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark - XML read").master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.jars", jar_path) \
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", jar_path) \
    .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", jar_path) \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", jar_path) \
    .getOrCreate()

xml_schema = StructType()
xml_schema.add("id", StringType(), True)
x1000 = StructType([
    StructField("X_PAT",
                ArrayType(StructType([
                    StructField("X_PAT01", StringType()),
                    StructField("X_PAT02", StringType()),
                    StructField("X_PAT03", StringType())]))),
])
xml_schema.add("X1000", x1000, True)

df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "root_tag").option("valueTag", False) \
    .load("root_tag.xml", schema=xml_schema)

df.select("id", "X1000.X_PAT").show(truncate=False)
```

I get the output as below:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
|id          |X_PAT                                       |
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
|fff9        |[[IC1, SUPPORT1, TE1], [IC2, SUPPORT2, TE2]]|
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

but I want the X_PAT to be flatten and create multiple columns like below then I will rename the colums.

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|id   |X_PAT01|X_PAT02|X_PAT03|X_PAT01|X_PAT02|X_PAT03|
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|fff9 |IC1    |SUPPORT1|TE1   |IC2   |SUPPORT2|TE2    |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

then i would rename the new columns as below

```
id|XPAT_1_01|XPAT_1_02|XPAT_1_03|XPAT_2_01|XPAT_2_02|XPAT_2_03|
```

I tried using `X1000.X_PAT.*` but it is throwing below error
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(L_1000A, S_PER)`;'

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1',[['IC1', 'SUPPORT1', 'TE1'],['IC2', 'SUPPORT2', 'TE2']]),('2',[['IC1', 'SUPPORT1', 'TE1'],['IC2','SUPPORT2', 'TE2']])],['id','X_PAT01'])
```

[image]

Define a function to parse the data

```
def create_column(df):
    data = df.select('X_PAT01').collect()[0][0]
    for each_list in range(len(data)):
        for each_item in range(len(data[each_list])):
            df = df.withColumn('X_PAT_'+str(each_list)+'_0'+str(each_item), F.lit(data[each_list][each_item]))
    return df
```

calling

```
df = create_column(df)
```

output

[image]

Comment: collect()[0][0] - for all rows in a df it generates new columns from first row X_PAT01 value, which is not correct. 
And this program needs to process 1million+ xml files in this case use of `.collect()` and for loop will have performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach to horizontally explode array elements as per your requirement:

```
df2=(df1
     .select('id',
             *(col('X_PAT')
               .getItem(i) #Fetch the nested array elements
               .getItem(j) #Fetch the individual string elements from each nested array element
               .alias(f'X_PAT_{i+1}_{str(j+1).zfill(2)}') #Format the column alias
               for i in range(2) #outer loop
               for j in range(3) #inner loop
              )
            )
    )
```

Input vs Output:

```
Input(df1):

+----+--------------------------------------------+
|id  |X_PAT                                       |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
|fff9|[[IC1, SUPPORT1, TE1], [IC2, SUPPORT2, TE2]]|
+----+--------------------------------------------+

Output(df2):

+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  id|X_PAT_1_01|X_PAT_1_02|X_PAT_1_03|X_PAT_2_01|X_PAT_2_02|X_PAT_2_03|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|fff9|       IC1|  SUPPORT1|       TE1|       IC2|  SUPPORT2|       TE2|
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Although this involves for loops, as the operations are directly performed on the dataframe (without collecting/converting to RDD), you should not encounter any issue.